# Simplifying $ \sum _{n=0}^m\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m-n}}{\left(m-n\right)!} $ to $ \sum _{n=0}^m\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying the simplification of :
$$
   \sum _{n=0}^m\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m-n}}{\left(m-n\right)!}
$$
into
$$
   \sum _{n=0}^m\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}
$$

I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Replace $n$ with $m-n$ in the index. This is the the same thing as writing the sum from the other side i.e. starting with the last term first.

Comment: Simply write your sum, for example for $m=3$, without summation symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it can be simplified by assuming $t=m-n$, then the lower limit $n=0$ is $t=m$ and the upper limit is $t=0$, that is, the summation is:$$\sum_{t=m}^0 \frac{(-1)^t}{t!}$$ and reverse the limits in the sum.